# Can't close certain processes with AutoHotkey

Tags: .net, autohotkey

I'm having trouble creating a small AutoHotkey script to end all vsjitdebugger.exe processes on a test server. Here's the code I have:

```
Process, Exist, vsjitdebugger.exe
NewPID = %ErrorLevel%
if NewPID = 0
{
    MsgBox Process doesnt exist
}
else
{
    MsgBox Process exists
}


Process, WaitClose, vsjitdebugger.exe, 5
NewPID = %ErrorLevel%
if NewPID = 0
{
    MsgBox Process no longer exists
}
else
{
    MsgBox Process still exists
}
```

When run the script tells me that the (vsjitdebugger.exe) process exists, as I would expect, but when WaitClose happens it still tells me that process(es) exist, and when I look in the Task Manager the same amount of vsjitdebugger.exe processes are still running.

I am able to end the vsjitdebugger.exe processes manually using Task Manager.

Basically I am unable to end these processes. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

**Update**: I've also tried this simple loop too, but with no avail:

```
Loop, 100
{
    Process, Close, vsjitdebugger.exe
}
```

**Update 2**: I tried the following code suggested below, but it just stays in the loop forever and no processes are killed:

```
Loop
{
    Process, Close, vsjitdebugger.exe
    Process, wait, vsjitdebugger.exe, 0.1             
    NewPID = %ErrorLevel%
    if NewPID = 0
    {
        break
    }   
}
```

Comment: FYI On Windows 7 I have to run AutoHotkey as Administrator to make it close some tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a system with taskkill.exe on it (I know Windows XP does, and I believe all versions after that do too), you can use this line:

```
Run, %comspec% /c "taskkill /F /IM vsjitdebugger /T"
```

Comment: Great that worked. I wonder why Process, Close doesn't work but calling taskkill does?

Comment: It's probably related to the forceful killing of the process or killing of the tree of processes that were spawned by it.  That's what the /F and /T flags were for.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have Microsoft Visual Studio installed on my computer, so I could not test using the exact process. I used notepad.exe instead. Using the simple loop you posted, I was able to successfully close 10 instances of notepad.

The following code worked on my computer (WinXP SP3) to close all instances of notepad.exe

```
Process, Exist, notepad.exe
NewPID = %ErrorLevel%
if NewPID = 0
{
    MsgBox, Process doesnt exist
}
else
{
    MsgBox, Process exists
}

Loop
{
    Process, Close, Notepad.exe
    Process, wait, Notepad.exe, 0.1     
    NewPID = %ErrorLevel%
    if NewPID = 0
    {
        break
    }   
}
Process, WaitClose, Notepad.exe
MsgBox, this works
```

I am not sure if this may be the cause of the any of the issues, but the **WaitClose** command does not close the process, it only waits for the process to no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to Windows 7 and found I had the same problem with not being able to close a process. What worked for me was running the program in XP compatibility mode.

Comment: On Windows 7 I have to run my AutoHotkey as administrator in order to get Process, Close, iexplore.exe to work